# Pourquoi Wikipédia, mais le Wiktionnaire ?

Tags: noms-propres, articles

Pourquoi le nom officiel de la version francophone de [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/) est-elle *[**le** Wiktionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/)*, avec un article et une majuscule ? C'est manifestement un nom propre (commençant par une majuscule), pourquoi a-t-on choisi de lui mettre un article, contrairement par exemple à ses frères [Wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/), [Wikimedia](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Accueil?uselang=fr) (sans accent), [Wikisource](http://fr.wikisource.org/), [Wikiversité](http://fr.wikiversity.org/), etc. ?

Comment: Note que la page de garde de [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Main_Page) utilise aussi l'article en anglais : _Welcome to the English-language Wiktionary_ — mais ils y ont l'air moins cohérents. A demander sur EL&U, peut-être ?

Comment: Des fois il vaut mieux ne pas se poser de questions...

Answer (score 7):

Difficile de répondre avec précision car cela n'est pas tant lié aux règles de la langue française qu'au choix des éditeurs de ces sites et à la façon dont les phrases qui utilisent ces mots sonnent en français :

*Je vais regarder dans le Wikitionnaire* sonne mieux que *je vais regarder sur Wikitionnaire*, alors que *je vais regarder sur Wikipédia* sonne mieux que *je vais regarder dans le Wikipédia*. C'est une bonne raison d'ajouter un article au premier mais pas au second.

Et l'un sonne mieux que l'autre simplement car *Wikitionnaire* rappelle le mot *dictionnaire*, ce qui n'est pas le cas de *Wikipédia* (on dit *encyclopédie*, pas *encyclopédia*). Mais si *Wikipédia* s'appellait *la Wikipédie*, peut-être dirait-on *je vais regarder dans la Wikipédie*.

*Wikiversité*, quant à elle, supporterait l'article aussi bien qu'elle s'en passe. *Je vais à la Wikiversité* sonnerait convenablement. Mais comme on ne va pas *à* un site web, mais *sur*, voire *on regarde dans*, on peut supposer que c'est ce qui a déterminé l'absence d'article.

Comment: La question porte sur le choix « officiel, » pas sur l'usage des utilisateurs. Je connais pas mal de gens (et j'en fais assurément partie) qui disent « la wikipédia. »

Comment: Je dis *sur Wiktionnary* et *sur Wikipédia*, faute de savoir si c'est le Wiktionnaire ou le Wikitionnaire. Si je disais *dedans*, alors je dirais *dans la Wikipédia* (et ça me ferai penser à une encyclopédie, comme si je disais *je vais regarder dans l'encyclopedia universalis*) (j'empapaoutre les majuscules, le cas échéant).

Answer (score 5):

On cherche dans le dictionnaire, et donc on cherche aussi dans *le* Wiktionnaire. Pas besoin d'aller chercher beaucoup plus loin je pense.

Pour développer un peu, je vois mal comment un second wiktionnaire (sans majuscule) pourrait voir le jour, et par conséquent, *le* semble approprié. Quant à la majuscule, ce serait sûrement trop présomptueux de s'appeler « le wiktionnaire », même malgré cela… À peu près autant qu'un pavé qui s'intitulerait « le dictionnaire ».

Pour finir, si Wikipédia s'appelait Wiklopédie, je parie qu'on irait aussi chercher dans la Wiklopédie.

Comment: Et pourtant *Wikiversité* n'a pas d'article.

Comment: @Gilles on dit aussi « la Wikiversité » sur [Wikiversité](http://fr.wikiversity.org/wiki/Wikiversit%C3%A9:%C3%80_propos)

Comment: la "Wikipédie", non? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Parce que c'est l'orthographe locale (*le Wiktionnaire*) d'une marque déposée (*Wiktionary*), [telle que promue par le détenteur de la marque](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiktionnaire) ?

La règle pour l'orthographe des marques commerciales, c'est bien de suivre l'usage du détenteur. Les exceptions se créent quand l'usage devient courant (*un coca* au lieu d'*un coca-cola*), or le terme *Wiktionaire* n'en est pas encore là.

Comment: Mouais, tu réponds à « pourquoi le ciel est-il bleu » par « parce que le pic de fréquence est autour de 650 THz ». Bon, je ne demandais pas explicitement une explication moins superficielle, mais ce que je veux savoir, c'est pourquoi les gens qui ont choisi le nom ont fait ce choix.

Comment: @Gilles alors pour moi la réponse est « ça n'a pas sa place sur FL&U, mais sur Marketing.SE, BrandNaming.SE ou autre ». En me faisant l'avocat du diable, c'est une question de type « pourquoi la marque X a-t-elle nommée tel produit Y », ce qui n'a pas sa place ici…