# Genre de Wikipédia (le ou la Wikipédia?)

Tags: genre

La plupart du temps, on consulte Wikipédia, ou on se rend sur Wikipédia, on cherche une réponse sur Wikipédia.

Pas besoin d’article défini pour l’introduire, apparemment, puisque c’est un nom propre. Et que si l’on est polyglotte, trouver une information sur Wikipédia, que ce soit en arabe, en finnois ou en français, c’est encore grosso-modo le même lieu, puisque les articles existant en plusieurs langues sont liés directement dans les pages consultées, et que le projet a été conçu pour être multilingue, dès le début ou du moins, si je fais erreur, très peu après sa création.

Cependant, j’ai voulu aujourd’hui mentionner que l’information que je citais provenait du pan anglais du grand tout wikipédiesque. J’aurais pu bien entendu allonger le discours pour mentionner la chose comme je viens de le faire, mais c’est lassant et ça détourne l’attention du point principal de la phrase, qui n’était pas destinée à être une longue élaboration sur le caractère multilingue du projet Wikipédia.

Mon naturel s’est exprimé en disant *« **le** Wikipédia anglais »*.

Bon ! Si l’on retrace la source du mot *Wikipédia*, on retrouve l’anglais *Wikipedia*, un mot-valise combinant [wiki](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki), terme d’origine hawaïenne, francisé au masculin pour la petite histoire, et *encyclopedia*, encyclopédie, nom féminin en français. Il s’agit bien d’un type d’encyclopédie. À la limite on pourrait aussi dire qu’il s’agit d’un type de wiki, mais ce serait davantage de façon détournée, par métonymie, que directement.

Mais le fait que le suffixe (ou peut-être devrait-on plutôt dire la finale) *-pedia* n’ait pas été francisé rend moins spontanée l’attribution du genre féminin, au point que naturellement j’ai donné le genre masculin au terme *Wikipédia*.

- Quel genre, donc, devrait-on attribuer à Wikipédia, dans le contexte particulier où l’un ou quelques-uns de ses volets sont désignés en opposition aux autres, cas où la désignation, à tort ou à raison, devient une valeur dénombrable ?
- L’usage seul est-il maître sur cette question ? Certaines institutions se sont-elles déjà prononcées ? Y aurait-il des variations en fonction de l’origine géographique des locuteurs consultés ?

Comment: Je lie [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1194/pourquoi-wikip%C3%A9dia-mais-le-wiktionnaire) concernant l’usage de Wikipédia en absolu, mais **du** Wiktionnaire. C’est apparenté, mais pas ce que je cherche à savoir ici.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wikipedia est rarement utilisé avec un article, mais quand c'est le cas (c'est à dire quand Wikipédia est suivi d'un qualificatif), l'usage du masculin l'emporte.

Google trouve environ 140 pages avec ***le*** Wikipedia, en particulier dans la presse, contre environ 80 avec ***la*** Wikipedia, dont de nombreuses occurrences sur Wikipédia même.

Quelques exemples masculins :

- [Yuka, le Wikipédia de l'alimentation, *Le Parisien*, 2018](http://www.leparisien.fr/societe/yuka-le-wikipedia-de-l-alimentation-qui-vous-aide-a-manger-mieux-13-08-2018-7851375.php)
- [Pour construire leurs meubles eux-mêmes, ils créent le Wikipedia du bricolage, *20 minutes*, 2016](https://www.20minutes.fr/magazine/economie-collaborative/services-collaboratif/pour-construire-leurs-meubles-eux-memes-ils-creent-le-wikipedia-du-bricolage-262452/)
- [Jimmy Wales annonce le lancement de Wikitribune, le "Wikipédia de l’actualité" qui veut lutter contre les fake news, *France 24*, 2017](https://www.france24.com/fr/20170425-jimmy-wales-annonce-le-lancement-wikitribune-le-wikipedia-actualite-veut-lutter-contre-fake-news)
- [Wollol. Le « Wikipédia » des souvenirs, *Le Télégramme*, 2018](https://www.letelegramme.fr/cotes-darmor/lannion/wollol-le-wikipedia-des-souvenirs-28-03-2018-11903965.php)
- [Wikidata, le Wikipédia que vous utiliserez bientôt tous, *L'Obs*, 2013](https://www.nouvelobs.com/rue89/rue89-hotel-wikipedia/20130617.RUE7986/wikidata-le-wikipedia-que-vous-utiliserez-bientot-tous.html)

et un féminin :

- [Sopa : la Wikipédia francophone pas solidaire de la grève anglophone, L'Obs, 2012](https://www.nouvelobs.com/rue89/rue89-hotel-wikipedia/20120117.RUE4319/sopa-la-wikipedia-francophone-pas-solidaire-de-la-greve-anglophone.html)

Ce qui peut expliquer cette préférence qui va donc à l'encontre de celle de Wikipédia est le fait que *wiki* est toujours utilisé au masculin ([un wiki](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki)) et que la terminaison *-édia* ne se rencontre, si on se limite aux mots courants, guère que dans *média* et ses dérivés, *multimédia*, *mass media*, tous masculins.

Le féminin peut cependant se défendre par la proximité avec *encyclopédie* et *encyclopædia*.

Comment: Merci! Un beau tour d'horizon et une vision élargie qui va au-delà de l'auto-déclaration et justifie les deux points de vue, les montrant non nez-à-nez, mais leur laissant du moins à chacun leur raison d'être. Comment se présente la France face à l'attribution du genre? Des concentrations locales d'irréductibles du féminin ou du masculin, ou assez homogène avec la vision personnelle qui domine plutôt la tendance générale?

Comment: Je remarque aussi à l'instant que l'exemple féminin que vous proposez traite spécifiquement de Wikipédia (de son volet français en opposition à celui anglais), alors que l'ensemble des autres comparent une entité différente en lui attribuant un statut (officieux) de Wikipédia. Une tendance? Doit-on y lire quelque chose ou n'est-ce qu'un hasard que j'analyse trop loin?

Comment: Je pense que c'est un hasard.

Comment: L'usage d'un article quand on ajoute un qualificatif est parfaitement cohérent, comme on dirait "*Rutube, le youtube russe*" ou "*le facebook des 8-13 ans*" (c'est des exemples au pif). Que je sache aucun des exemples ne l'utilise seul, comme "*trouvé sur le Wikipedia.*"

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Oui, c'est le seul cas qui se défende. J'ai eu récemment une discussion interminable avec LPH qui refuse de le reconnaître, mais je viens de voir que tu lui à répondu.

Comment: @jlliagre C'est pour ça que je suis arrivé ici ^^

Comment: @jlliagre Quand wikipédia elle-même n'utilise pas d'article je comprends même pas comment on peut défendre l'usage de l'article. Depuis quand ça marche comme ça ?

Comment: @TeleportingGoat LPH défend parfois des causes encore plus absurdes...

Answer (score 6):

Sur la question précise, et puisque l'on est bien dans le domaine de l'arbitraire, il me semble que la seule autorité habilitée à se prononcer est Wikipédia... elle... lui... soi-même! ;-)

Et... le moins que l'on puisse dire est que, de ce coté... la chose semble décidée sans la moindre ambigüité :

- [*"Wikipédia est réalis**ée**... Wikipédia est assez éloign**ée**..."*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikip%C3%A9dia)
- [*"Wikipédia fut d'abord cré**ée**"... la Chine bloque l'accès à **la** Wikipédia chinois**e**.](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histoire_de_Wikip%C3%A9dia)

ergo : ***La*** Wikipédia anglais**e**

Il m'arrive de fréquenter la version allemande, très explicite elle aussi, ce qui fait déclarer à *Das freie Wörterbuch* : [***Substantiv, f***](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wikipedia)

Dans le cadre plus général de la définition du genre d'un néologisme, la décision pourrait effectivement être différente dans la mesure où, comme tu l'as observé le suffixe à été francisé de façon pour le moins curieuse, mais... en est-ce même un ? Avec les mots valises, c'est assez difficile à déterminer.

Comment: Le suffixe en est un, sans conteste, en anglais. Il a été francisé tel quel et non en fonction d'un équivalent français. Je ne suis pas convaincu que Wikipédia, à cause de sa nature wiki, soit la seule ou même la plus digne référence en fait de  détermination du genre, mais c'est une référence qui en vaut certainement une autre jusqu'à preuve du contraire. Merci de votre réponse.

Comment: @Montéedelait : L'accent aigu ne permet pas vraiment de dire que la fin du mot (que je répugne à appeler suffixe) a été francisée telle quelle. L'allemand pour qui *encyclopédie* se dit *Enzyklop**ä**die* a été plus fidèle dans la germanisation.

Comment: @Montéedelait : Et puis enfin... Je crois dans l'idée fondatrice réside le souhait de voir les utilisateurs / contributeurs s'approprier l'outil. On ne travaille bien avec un outil que lorsqu'on se l'est approprié. Dans ce sens, la détermination du genre joue son rôle dans l'appropriation. Que chacun soit libre de déterminer le genre qui lui va me semble donc dans la nature de la chose. Des amis disent *mon 500* pour parler de leur moto. Curieusement, les mêmes diront *ma 750* quand ils passent à la cylindrée supérieure... Après tout... ils ont bien le droit s'ils se sentent mieux ainsi dessus

Comment: Ce fameux accent aigu. C'est la deuxième fois cette semaine que j'affirme qu'un mot a été introduit en français avec son orthographe d'origine et que j'oublie de remarquer qu'un accent aigu y a en fait été ajouté. Merci de me remettre à ma place.

Comment: Par ailleurs, l'anglais est plus laxiste en général que le français sur la notion de suffixe. Il est vrai que dans le sens français de suffixe, -pédia ou même -pédie ne se qualifieraient pas. Mais en anglais, j'aurais tendance à dire que c'en est un, parce que la transition allant de terminaison curieuse à suffixe productif dans les néologismes y est en général beaucoup plus courte.

Comment: @Montée de lait : Te remettre à ta place ??? EEeKkk! De grâce ne le prends pas ainsi. Pas de ça entre nous mon ami(e). Unze je me permettrais pas et deuze, sur un sujet gouverné par l'arbitraire, ce serait vraiment absurde de ma part.

Comment: Je ne le prends pas mal et ça ne me dérange pas de me faire remettre à ma place, expression que j'utilise régulièrement dans un sens très adouci et qui pourrait s'apparenter à *remettre les pendules à l'heure*. Pas de rancœur pour moi.

Answer (score 5):

Dans l'ensemble, il est clair que l'usage a établi la construction sans article comme dominante, comme c'est le cas pour la majorité des noms de marque ou de service aujourd'hui (*on consulte Google, YouTube, Linguee, Reverso, Libération*, etc.), sauf quand ils correspondent immédiatement, sémantiquement *et* morphologiquement, à un substantif (comme le rappellent @Montée-de-lait et @Gilles, *on consulte **le** Wiktionnaire*, parce que ça ressemble à *un dictionnaire* ; en Belgique, *on regarde **la** RTBF*, parce que c'est *la radio-télévision belge*, mais *on regarde TF1, France 2*, etc.).

Ceci étant dit, il existe des cas où l'on pourrait vouloir utiliser l'article, comme dans les structures avec complément du nom : « la Wikipédia de 2015 » (*[L'Obs](https://www.nouvelobs.com/rue89/rue89-hotel-wikipedia/20120812.RUE1835/a-quoi-ressemblera-wikipedia-en-2015.html)*) ou « Bitcoin, le Wikipédia de la finance » (*[Contrepoints](https://www.contrepoints.org/2015/11/01/227403-bitcoin-le-wikipedia-de-la-finance)*). Et même sans cela, la question de son genre se pose dans tous les cas, ne fut-ce que pour l'accord d'adjectifs ou de participes passés, comme dans les exemples donnés par @aCOSwt.

### Pourquoi certains masculinisent-ils ?

(*Wikipédia est régulièrement mis à jour*, *le Wikipédia anglophone*)

Les substantifs en anglais sont neutres, or le français n'a pas de neutre. En l'absence de mot français proche qui pousse à calquer le genre du mot français sur le mot anglais (ex. *une overdose*, influencé par *dose*; *une interview*, par *entrevue*), les emprunts à l'anglais ont tendance à être masculinisés :

> Il y a une nette tendance à la masculinisation des emprunts inconnus ou peu connus, en l'absence d'un genre neutre. [...] . Celle-ci voudrait que tout nom inanimé emprunté à l'anglais soit au masculin lorsqu'il n'existe pas de raisons puissantes pour qu'il soit au féminin. ([Guilford, 1999: “L’attribution du genre aux emprunts à l’anglais”, *La Linguistique, 35*(1), p. 85.](http://www.jstor.org/stable/30249173))

Il me semble que c'est cette tendance qui explique l'attribution du masculin, par exemple dans l'expression spontanée de @Montée-de-lait, comme on a des emprunts à l'anglais dont le genre fluctue sous des influences contradictoires (p.ex. : *le team* par masculinisation du neutre, mais *la team* par calque de *l'équipe* ).

### Pourquoi certains féminisent-ils ?

(*Wikipédia est régulièrement mise à jour*, *la Wikipédia anglophone*)

Avant tout par analogie sémantique (il s'agit d'**une** encylopédie).

### Quel genre choisir alors ?

L'usage est, à mon avis, plutôt en faveur du **féminin**.

- Sur Wikipédia même, comme l'ont montré @aCOSwt et @Dimitris: [« Wikipédia est réalisée... », « La Wikipédia en anglais... »](http://www.jstor.org/stable/30249173).
- Mais aussi de manière plus générale : en nombre de *hits* sur Google News, ±1 540 pour « le Wikipédia » contre ±28 000 pour « la Wikipédia » (à prendre avec des pincettes, vu les limites de ces mesures grossières).
- Sur corpus (bigrammes du corpus web français (2011) de [HC Corpora](http://corpora.epizy.com/corpora.html?i=1), nettement plus fiable que les résultats de Google, puisque contrôlable) : 20 occurrences pour « la wikipédia » contre 4 pour « le wikipédia » (avec accent, peu importe la casse).
- Le fait même que les 5 exemples de masculin donnés par @jlliagre correspondent à une construction très spécifique avec complément du nom (« [Produit], le ‘Wikipédia’ du/de la [spécialité] ») tend selon moi à démontrer la rareté du masculin, même si cela confirme qu'il y a des hésitations/fluctuations sur le genre, voire qu'il y a peut-être des usages divergents selon les constructions syntaxiques.

Answer (score 3):

D'après wikipédia elle-même :

> Historiquement, l'anglais a été la principale langue utilisée, avant
>   qu'une multitude de sites ne soient ouverts dans d'autres langues,
>   notamment la Wikipédia en français le 23 mars 2001 (302 langues en
>   octobre 2018). **La Wikipédia** en anglais a toujours conservé cette
>   importance relative : le nombre d'articles s'élève à plus de cinq
>   millions.

Source :

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikip%C3%A9dia

Answer (score 2):

Ce qui est remarquable avant tout, c'est qu'on utilise *wikipédia* ou *wikipedia* ou *Wikipedia* (il y a hésitation pour ma part entre les diverses orthographes) sans article la plupart du temps.  On peut assimiler *wikipedia* aux noms de marque, sous-catégorie de noms propres, qui s'emploient sans article.  On dit par exemple :

- Renault a réalisé des bénéfices exceptionnels.
- Larousse sort un nouveau dictionnaire

Par contre, lorsqu'un substantif est sous-entendu, l'article apparaît, comme dans :

- J'ai acheté une Renault. (Sous-entendu *voiture*)
- J'ai vérifié le sens du mot dans le Larousse.  (Sous-entendu *dictionnaire*)

Mais, selon ce qui est sous-entendu, on dira :

- Renault aujourd'hui n'a rien à voir avec le Renault des années 80.  (Sous-entendu *groupe* ou *constructeur*)

ou bien, pourquoi pas,

- Renault aujourd'hui n'a rien à voir avec la Renault des années 80.  (Sous-entendu *société* ou *entreprise*).

Toujours est-il qu'à se fonder sur des sous-entendus que tout le monde ne partage pas forcément, l'usage est marqué par des hésitations quant au genre de cette catégorie de mots.  Pour ce qui est de *wikipedia*, on constate une fluctuation entre :

- Vérifie sur la wikipédia française (sous-entendu *encyclopédie* ou peut-être *version*)
- Vérifie sur le wikipédia français (sous-entendu *site*)

Comment: [Alors que c'est le Wiktionnaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1194/pourquoi-wikip%C3%A9dia-mais-le-wiktionnaire).

Answer (score -4):

« Pas besoin d'article défini pour l'introduire », il me semble, fait abstraction d'un état de chose par trop négligé. Il est incontestable que pour ce type d'ouvrage le français traditionnel a besoin d'un article : on ne trouve pas un mot « dans Larousse » ou « dans Robert » et encore moins « dans Dictionnaire de l'Académie »; de même on ne dit pas « J'ai trouvé ce renseignement dans Universalis/Encyclopédie Universalis. » mais «J'ai trouvé ce renseignement dans **l'Universalis/l'Encyclopédie Universalis**. ». Il n'y a aucune contestation là-dessus, tous ces noms sont des noms propres. Pourquoi tout d'un coup n'y aurait-il pas besoin d'article, en quoi est-ce que le nom propre « Wikipédia » diffère ? En rien, sauf en cela que c'est le nom d'un concept qui est détaché du contexte culturel français de par son origine, qui n'est pas française, sauf que c'est un mot que l'esprit français contemporain aveuglé par l'omniprésence de la culture anglo-saxonne, aveuglé par son succès hégémonique, ne conçoit plus selon les normes de sa propre langue, parce que c'est un mot qu'il n'arrive pas à concevoir comme tout simplement un autre nom de chose, pour lequel en français il n'existe pas de degré de personnalisation. Cette déconnexion n'est pas un phénomène négligeable, loin de là, elle est bien réelle et elle est l'explication de chamboulements importants qui menacent de changer de manière drastique et pour toujours la langue française.

Il y a donc besoin d'un article pour garder à la langue française son unité et il n'y a qu'un article, qui s'impose, encore une fois pour garder à la langue son unité; cet article c'est « **la**  » : le concept qui sous-tend celui de « Wikipédia » c'est le concept fondamental d'encyclopédie, ce projet que le terme « Wikipédia » désigne est essentiellement une encyclopédie. On doit donc dire « **la Wikipédia**».

Comment: Pour justifier un -1 : *"l'esprit français contemporain aveuglé par l'omniprésence..."* Serait-il possible de répondre à une question sans pour autant balancer des phantasmes ?

Comment: @aCOSwt Il ne s'agit pas de phantasmes; n'êtes-vous pas conscient de la masse de vocabullaire qui nous vient de l'anglais, de l'anglais américain et de l'anglais Britannique? N'êtes vous pas conscient de l'attrait qu'à l'homme français contemporain pour  « tout » ce qui est anglais et américain? Je ne fais pas de cela une faute, je ne culpabilise pas ce comportement, néanmoins, mais c'est une évidence. Alors vous êtes le responsable de ce -1…Vous êtes bien sévère avec moi!

Comment: Vous êtes absolument libre de vos opinions, des vues de **votre** esprit. Mais alors faites de **votre esprit** le sujet de cette phrase et non *l'esprit français*. N'est-ce pas vous qui avez dans le méta dénoncé un manque de professionnalisme sur FSE ?

Comment: @aCOSwt Oui, j'ai bien fait des remarques à propos de cela; pourquoi donc ne pas l'avoir fait? Le FSE ne serait-il pas passible de criticisme? Est-ce qu'il doit absolument passer pour un paragon de perfection? Ne pourrait-il pas comme tout autre chose avoir des défaut? Comment les corriger si on n'en parle pas, si on ne met pas un mot sur ces défaut? Je crois que j'explique suffisamment des états de chose indéniables en rapport avec cette critique, ce n'est pas une critique gratuite. Je crois, de totute façon, que je ne caractérise pas le problème comme étant un manque (continué)

Comment: @aCOSwt de professionnalisme, c'est à dire un manque total de professionnalisme; je crois vouloir dire plutôt que le degré de professionnalisme actuel pourrait être augmenté si certains états de chose pouvaient être changés. Si je ne l'ai pas fait, c'est une erreur de ma part et je suis prêt à remédier à cette inexactitude. Il est dommage que vous ayez à faire les remarques que vous avez concernant ce sujet dans le présent espace pour les commentaires, je ne vois pas ce qui m'aurait empêcher de vous répondre dans le méta.

Comment: @Montéedelait Avez-vous jamais entendu parler de l'existence d'une langue quasiment parallèle au chinois, le chinois simplifié ? Avez- vous jamais entendu parler de l'élimination de 17 règles d'utilisation des virgules en allemand ? Avez-vous jamais entendu parler même des réformes orthographiques du français (de l'incroyable désordre que ça a causé) ? N'avez-vous jamais entendu parler de l'association anglaise du XIXe siècle dont le but était de simplifier l'orthographe de l'anglais ? Que signifie pour vous ce soucis universel et constant de retour en arrière ?

Comment: @LPH           Diriez-vous "le Larousse est publié par Larousse" ou "le Larousse est publié par le Larousse"?

Comment: @petitrien Je m'en tiendrais  au formules connues : publié par Larousse, publié chez Larousse, publié aux éditions Larousse ; le Larousse n'est qu'une  des publication de cette maison, même si la plus importante.